# SPContext.Current is null while calling SPContext.Current.Web.EnsureUser() method

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, spweb, spcontext, httpcontext

`SPContext.Current` is null while calling `SPContext.Current.Web.EnsureUser()` method.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the context of your code? Web part? Event receiver?...

Comment: I'm trying to fetch users [author, editor) at item level using SPContext.Current.Web.EnsureUser()

Comment: What's the context? A Web part, a job, a PowerShell command, ...? That's our question!

Comment: Code is being called from ItemUpdated event

Comment: Not enough: you mean a list event reveiver, right? This can be triggered in a Web context (item udpated from the UI) or not (item updated from a workflow, from PowerShell, from a job...). Please, read my answer below, as I already explained this.

Answer (score 1):

`SPContext.Current` can only be used from a Web context.

This means it works fine as long as an `HttpContext` exists.

By definition, this is always the case for **Web parts**, **controls** and **Web pages**.

For **list event receivers** and **feature event receivers**, it may or it may not be available: it depends on how the item (resp. the feature) as been added (resp. activated): from the UI (most common case: `SPContext.Current` is then available), from PowerShell (not available), from custom .exe (not available)...
In a feature event receiver you can safely use `properties.Feature.Parent` instead.
In a list event receiver, you can easily get access to the Web that originated the event with `properties.Web`.

For **workflows**, it also depends, as a workflow action may run in the Web context that triggered it (OK) or in a job (KO).

**Jobs** always run in a dedicated process (owstimer.exe) where `SPContext.Current` is never available. The concept of "contextual Web" has no signification here, since a job runs out of any user interaction, and, most of the time, simply loops through all existing sites.

Answer (score 0):

SPContext.Current is not available in all scopes - it will work in Event Receivers and web service calls, but will be null in Timer Jobs and within RunWithElevatedPrivileges (as suggested [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74205/spcontext-current-is-null-for-ihttphandler)). From where are you trying to access SPContext.Current?